# Execute Executable with Electronjs

Tags: electron

How do you execute an executable in electron-js (with its path given)?

I want to start within my application any other application. My operating system is Windows, so I'm looking for answers for Windows, but when there is also a solution for Linux I'm not reluctant in getting to know this solution.

For Example:

```js
function startApk() {
    let path = "C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe";
    <!-- Here I want my program to be executed -->
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback), execFile() is more performant than exec():

> The child_process.execFile() function is similar to
>   child_process.exec() except that it does not spawn a shell by default.
>   Rather, the specified executable file is spawned directly as a new
>   process making it slightly more efficient than child_process.exec().

Answer (score 1):

One approach as I figured would be:

```js
let path = "C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe";
exec(`"${path}"`, (error) => { // use extra "" around path when the path contains spaces
    if (error) {
            // command couldn't be executed, handle error
            return;
        }
    });
```

I'm still open for other and better solutions.